# Upload file from directory path

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, filestream

My application has a feature that allows users upload files, but I only  know getting the file using HttpPostedFileBase. Now I need to load a large quantity of documents from a specific directory but I don't know how to get those file once I can't use HttpPostedFileBase.

The files are .pdf, but I think this doesn't matter once I don't need to read or open the file content.

Thank you.

Comment: So what is your question? Please rephrase to clarify.

Comment: Do you mean that you need to open server-side files using server-side code?  Or are you trying to get your server-side code to automatically read client-side files (which isn't possible)?  Or something else?

Comment: I want to read a amount of pdf from an hard drive and save into the server, using c#.

Comment: I want to manipulate the files that I will read from an Hard Drive as I used to with file that was the type HttpPostedFileBase. I alredy have a method to save into my server I just need the file with  similar properties.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to copy image from one path to another in server side. you can use the following code.

```
 Public void CopyFiles(string sourcePath,string destinationPath)
 {
   string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath);

   foreach(string file in files)
   {
     System.IO.File.Copy(sourcePath,destinationPath);  
   }
```

}

Comment: are pdf documents, it's that ok?

Answer (score 0):

**Upload multiple files, eg. PDFs :**

`public ActionResult UploadMethod(HttpPostedFileBase file)`

to this:

`public ActionResult UploadMethod(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)`

And you also need `<input type="file" multiple>` in front-end.

**Get a list of uploaded files with similar properties as the file from HttpPostedFileBase:**

`DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"F:\WINNT");`

`FileInfo[] pdfFiles = dir.GetFiles("*.pdf);`

And now you can do alot: `pdfFiles[0].Name` or `pdfFiles[0].toString()` wich returns the path.

Comment: I want to get the file from hardrive.

Comment: If you need to upload multiple files, this is what I posted in my answer, if you just want to read files from a folder and make a list: `string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\");
`

Comment: or maybe you want that : `FileInfo[] bmpfiles = dir.GetFiles("*.pdf);` where dir points to the location on disk....